# Overlay pd.DataFrame rows to a list of lists per column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that I have two pandas DataFrames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4], 'b': [5], 'c': [6]})
```

I would like to obtain a list of lists which hold the values per column, looking as follows

```
> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

How could that be done without iterating over the columns?

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2]).to_numpy().T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`.

```
>>> list(zip(*df1.values, *df2.values))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

>>> list(map(list, zip(*df1.values, *df2.values)))
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```